# Is 0.0.0.0 in Django ALLOWED_HOSTS a security risk?

Tags: django

There's plenty of these questions based on configuration of Django's settings, but I'm asking from a security perspective--

**Background:** This is (obviously) a Django app which I am running inside a Docker container; gunicorn is running in that container and set to listen on port 8000 (`gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000`). Nginx is public-facing (listening on 80) and running in a separate container.  Nginx sends the requests to the Django container over the internal network setup by docker-compose.

At the moment, I'm running this on a cloud machine with an ephemeral IP.  I have added that to my ALLOWED_HOSTS so that it reads `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['XX.XXX.XX.XX']` where `xx.xxx.xx.xx` is the actual IP. *The application works.*

**My question:**
My application monitoring just informed me of an apparent error which read:

```
api_1    | 2020-07-29 16:50:24,498 django.security.DisallowedHost.response_for_exception ERROR    
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

This was *not* a request I made-- likely just some bot.

**Should I actually add `0.0.0.0` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? Or is that a security risk?** Will that allow bogus requests through? What does `0.0.0.0` mean in the context of my Django application? If it should only get receiving requests sent by the nginx server, shouldn't those all have the xx.xxx.xx.xx IP as the host header?

I don't necessarily want all these bot/scanning requests to fill-up my application monitoring with junk and this does not seem to be a "real" error. My understanding of networking is limited, so I apologize if this is a simple question.

Thanks!

Comment: You may not need to expose 0.0.0.0 externally, but only within a container. Then you could use  127.0.0.0.1 for the external, exposed port. I had a similar question with flask, which could help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709052/securing-a-localhost-port-for-a-flask-celery-app-running-locally-on-0-0-0-0-in-d/63864023#63864023